# How would I go about removing negative values from all columns in a Pyspark Dataframe?

Tags: python, pyspark

Hey guys i'm trying to remove negative values from a pyspark dataframe. I've tried

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

foo = udf(lambda x: not np.any(np.array(x)<0), BooleanType())
df.filter(foo('features')).show()
```

but i'm receiving a stage failure error

Comment: Do you want to remove negative value from whole dataframe or from specific column?

Answer (score 0):

*I considered that your dataframe name is df and you want to remove negative value from column "features"*

**Try below codes**

```
df = df.withColumn('flag', f.when(df["features"] < 0, 0).otherwise(1)).\
        filter('flag == "1"').\
        drop("flag")
```